# Can I use "spent" lemons (juiced) to preserve?

Tags: food-preservation, lemon

I'm about to juice 5 or 6 lemons, I'll zest maybe 2 of them. (I'm making a lemon cheesecake). Lemon isn't something I care to use very often, but I'm intrigued by 'preserved lemons', something I've never done (always a plus). It was cheaper to buy a five pound bag of lemons (11 total) than to buy 6 lemons individually, so I'll have 5 or 6 left over. Obviously the juiced and zested lemons are trash, but what about the intact rinds of the juiced lemons? Can I shove those in the jar with the salt too, along with my 5 or 6 remaining lemons? Or will that throw off some kind of magic ratio?

Comment: You can use the rinds of the juiced lemons and the juice from the zested lemons. If it turns out you don't have enough juice to cover the preserved lemons, you can also make candied lemon peel. I went through 200+ lemons in a week by making lemonade, preserved lemons, and candied peel with very little waste left.

Comment: Candied peel - nice idea! I suspect now that I will complete my little lemon adventure with nothing left but a few spent rinds, zest intact. I'm settling in for a long Alaskan winter, candied lemon peel could be a fun ingredient to have on hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recipe that i tried a while back. I wasnt too impressed with the spicy one. But overall good method and clear explanation. And sure get your extra zest in there too!

http://awesomepickle.com/make-pickled-lemons-two-ways/

Comment: So it seems the answer depends upon the juiciness of the lemons. I had been looking at this one [link](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/reviews/Preserved-Lemons-231570) and an America's Test Kitchen video. All three variants of technique say that the juice needs to cover the salt and lemons. So, it seems that I can squeeze a few more rinds in there IF there is enough juice.